# Python: what is the ast.FunctionType in python ast?

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, abstract-syntax-tree, python-ast

I don't pretend to have understood everything in python ast, but FunctionType is something that bothered me.

```py
mod = Module(stmt* body, type_ignore *type_ignores)
        | Interactive(stmt* body)
        | Expression(expr body)
        | FunctionType(expr* argtypes, expr returns)
        | Suite(stmt* body)
```

What can it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FunctionType` is the top-level symbol returned for parsing `# type: (args) -> return_type` comments for function types (as specified by [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/))

The only authoritative source for this I can find is the changelog for Python 3.8 where it was added: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#ast

You can parse this type of thing with `compile` or `ast.parse` with the `'func_type'` mode (where the mode would usually be `exec` for statements and `eval` for expressions).

This is only used (by external type checking software) if you are trying to annotate function return types with the Python 2 syntax, like:

```py
# Invalid syntax in Python 2
# def f(x: int, y: int) -> int:
#     return x * y

# Special type of type hint for functions in Python 2  (and also works in Python 3)
def f(x, y):
    # type: (int, int) -> int
    return x * y

# Or alternative syntax:
def f(
    x,  # type: int
    y   # type: int
):
    # type: (...) -> int
    return x * y
```

Normal type annotations can just be parsed in `'eval'` mode, but function type annotations can't be, so a new mode and top-level symbol was added:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Grammar/python.gram#L91

```gf
func_type[mod_ty]: '(' a=[type_expressions] ')' '->' b=expression NEWLINE* ENDMARKER { _PyAST_FunctionType(a, b, p->arena) }
```

Which can be used by type checkers to parse these types of comments:

```py
import ast

source = '''
def f(x, y):
    # type: (int, int) -> int
    return x * y
'''

module = ast.parse(source, mode='exec', type_comments=True)

class PrintFunctionTypes(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, f):
        print('FunctionDef:\n' + ast.dump(f))
        print('\ntype_comment:\n' + f.type_comment)
        parsed_comment = ast.parse(f.type_comment, mode='func_type')
        print('\nWhen parsed:\n' + ast.dump(parsed_comment))

PrintFunctionTypes().visit(module)
```

Which outputs:

```
FunctionDef:
FunctionDef(name='f', args=arguments(posonlyargs=[], args=[arg(arg='x'), arg(arg='y')], kwonlyargs=[], kw_defaults=[], defaults=[]), body=[Return(value=BinOp(left=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()), op=Mult(), right=Name(id='y', ctx=Load())))], decorator_list=[], type_comment='(int, int) -> int')

type_comment:
(int, int) -> int

When parsed:
FunctionType(argtypes=[Name(id='int', ctx=Load()), Name(id='int', ctx=Load())], returns=Name(id='int', ctx=Load()))
```